# Problems with open card Pay Pal standard plugin

Tags: php, opencart2.x

i'm having problem with OpenCart shop version 2.x PayPal Standard plugin.

2017-09-08 13:31:18 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN REQUEST:

> cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=7.13&invoice=2872+-+Oleg+Lopeta&protection_eligibility=Eligible&item_number1=&item_number2=&payer_id=MH5HLR9X2GMXC&payment_date=03%3A30%3A19+Sep+08%2C+2017+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&first_name=Oleg&mc_fee=0.59&notify_version=3.8&custom=2872&payer_status=verified&business=ebay%40rrr.lt&num_cart_items=2&verify_sign=AbzlMQfnGCW1kgs7W9U77Rx7TroaA8ihH-C5l6T2VSiTSwMlnI0mBcAy&payer_email=oleg.lopeta%40gmail.com&txn_id=7EL168808H347641D&payment_type=instant&last_name=Lopeta&item_name1=&receiver_email=ebay%40rrr.lt&item_name2=Siuntimas%2C+pakavimas%2C+nuolaidos+ir+mokes%1Aiai&payment_fee=&quantity1=1&quantity2=1&receiver_id=MNVALKUC7TZEC&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=2.48&mc_currency=EUR&mc_gross_2=4.65&residence_country=LT&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=&ipn_track_id=28598eaca014e

2017-09-08 13:31:18 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN RESPONSE: INVALID

We have request good and response somehow is invalid "**PP_STANDARD :: IPN RESPONSE: INVALID**"

so what we have done is commented the line:

```
// if ((strcmp($response, 'VERIFIED') == 0 || strcmp($response, 'UNVERIFIED') == 0) && isset($this->request->post['payment_status'])) {
```

Open Cart after the payment is done changing status to Payed, but is kind a hole in a code.

May be you guys already had the same problem and somehow fixed that ?

Thank You

Comment: Have you setup the paypal in opencart correctly. [Reference](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1809&actp=RSS)

Comment: Yes it is working and everything works fine, but after the payment is made, the open cart status is not changing to payed, so i've figured out that ipn request is coming, but ipn response is not coming, but invalid. So i've uncommented that part that checks if status is verified or not and it works but it kind a crack in the script and i want to fix it? any ideas? May be do you know some bug fix ?